# How to order dates on x-axis with ggplot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, melt

I am trying to use `ggplot` to plot a grouped barplot. I noticed that the date variable is considered as factor and while plotting R changes its order randomly.

I tried converting the date using `as.date(X,format="%m/%d/%Y")` but with no help.

Here is my code,

```
A<-data.frame(A)
A$Date<-as.Date(A$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
Name=XYZ
B<-A[c(1,2,5,6)]
C<-melt(B,id.vars='Date')
C$Date<-as.Date(C$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
ggplot(C,aes(x=Date,y=value))+
 geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity")+
 scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")+
 labs(x='Date',y='%Return')+ggtitle('Model')+
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=7,color="Black"))+
 theme(legend.position = 'bottom')+
 theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8))+coord_cartesian( ylim=c(-6, 6))
```

Before converting `Date` to the proper date format I got the below output but without the order of `Date`.

[image]!

After `Date` conversion, the output changes drastically:

[image]!

Not sure what I am missing out on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By default `ggplot` sorts factors alphabetically, so you could put your dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format to get them in the correct order but keep them as factors, if you want your chart like the first one.

Comment: Your code doesn't include test data. You can look at the `reorder` function, and perhaps use `ggplot scale_x_date`

Comment: In my experience, factor levels are actually used for ordering in ggplot.

Comment: Convert to Date format with "as.Date" and then use "as.yearmon" from "zoo" package.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I converted the date format to YYYY-MM-DD and it worked. I think its the default format for date factors.

Comment: Duplicate of [out of order date in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346031/out-of-order-date-in-ggplot2)